# translucent status bar on webview app

Tags: android, webview

Greeting guys, i'm an beginner android developer, and my question is...

is it possible to make translucent status bar on webview application which loads my website.

i've been playing with styles.xml but i've been unable to achieve the result i've wanted, i could make no status bar/navigation bar at all, but cant make them translusent like on pushbullet app or google experience launcher.

i'm using kitkat sdk and newest version of android studio.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by setting appropriate theme item.

For Android 3.0 and higher only

```
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
           parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

For Android 2.1 and higher (using AppCompat library)

```
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
           parent="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Examples taken from [Google Training documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/overlaying.html).